# Why doesn’t ‘the meaning is red’ make sense?

Tags: word-meaning

Question: The meaning of ‘Apple’ is fruit and the fruit is red. Is ‘the meaning is red’ semantically correct?

Answer: The fruit is most definitely not consistently red. Forget semantics here, the statement isn't logically or factually correct.

‘Meaning’ means what is meant and an ‘apple’ means fruit so what is meant is fruit but why doesn’t ‘the meaning [the apple] is red’ make sense? I can’t find the answer even though I’ve looked through many dictionaries.

Comment: The meaning of 'apple' is not a physical apple, but the concept of what the word represents (a type of fruit). Why do you persist in interpreting things in such strange ways?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Every word in a sentence means concept?

Comment: The meaning of a noun is a concept and not the thing itself, as Maciej explains in his answer.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, and I'm not going to be drawn into another long conversation going round and round in circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is formally called a [fallacy of four terms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_four_terms). When applying syllogistic reasoning, such as:

> Lions are cats.
>
> Cats have four legs.
>
> Therefore, lions have four legs.

you need to ensure the term used in both premises is the exact same term between them - not just the same *word*, but the same *concept*. For example, this is not valid reasoning:

> The definition of "felines" is "cats".
>
> Cats have four legs.
>
> *Therefore, the definition of "felines" has four legs.

because in the first sentence "cats" represents the word "cats" itself, while in the second sentence "cats" represents the actual creatures. A word is not the same as the concept described by that word, therefore the syllogism has four terms and is not valid.

Your example follows the same pattern - the first sentence refers to the word "fruit", and the second refers to what the word "fruit" represents.

Comment: This is a rather simplified explanation - if you want to discuss the distinctions between words and their meanings in more detail, you're probably better off on Philosophy.SE.